# Why are my NodeJS Protractor tests on Travis CI failing with make error

Tags: node.js, makefile, protractor, travis-ci

I'm trying to run my [protractor-example](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example) tests on Travis CI, but it keeps failing. Thinking it was my .travis.yml, so I stripped it down...

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
   node_js:
     - "0.10"

script:
    - echo "Hello..."
```

This, like all my previous attempts, ends with the following:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-5-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-2
git.1
0.13s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example.git qualityshepherd/protractor_example
Cloning into 'qualityshepherd/protractor_example'...
remote: Counting objects: 109, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 109 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (109/109), 15.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40/40), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd qualityshepherd/protractor_example
git.4
$ git checkout -qf 29c4ac38db161b95b5b05b6cb90881d9de2020f6
couchdb stop/waiting
0.55s$ nvm install 0.10
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using node v0.10.32
0.45s0.02s$ node --version
v0.10.32
0.45s$ npm --version
1.4.28
0.01s$ make test
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
The command "make test" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I'm not sure why it's running `make`... it never hits my `script`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think travis is expecting some way to actually run the integration tests. Either via a `Makefile` that expects `make test` or a `package.json` that works with `npm test`. Add a minimal `Makefile` or `package.json` and you should get past this error.